# Kafka Streams Exactly Once TransactionalIdAuthorizationException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My kafka streams application behaves fine with I am in an environment where my replication factor is 3 after setting the PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG to exactly_once.

However I have a dev environment where the replication factor must be one.  According to the documentation this OK for development only.  However even after I set the following configs to 1.  I still get a TransactionalIdAuthorizationException when starting up.

KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR

Answer (score 1):

Using transactions requires a minimum replication factor of 3 by default, ie, 3 brokers. You need to reconfigure the broker, to reduce those default setting to 1.

Comment: I did set the values to one.  "However even after I set the following configs to 1. I still get a TransactionalIdAuthorizationException when starting up."  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: You need to set corresponding ACLs, too.